# Do not output logs to screen when running Rails tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rake

I need to run the tests for my Rails application, but it seems that when I do `rake test:all`, I get all logs outputted to my screen, including all queries performed and debug messages.

Is there a way to just show how many tests passed/failed and the failures (if any?). Something similar to what Django tests output.

Comment: What testing framework you use?

Comment: The default one that comes with Rails.

Comment: default Rails [framework based on `MiniTest`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/activesupport.gemspec#L26), so i think you can use [MiniTest#Reporters](https://github.com/kern/minitest-reporters)

Comment: Isn't there some configuration option to suppress all those debug messages? I don't want to install yet another gem for this...

Comment: Just to know, I've tried using Minitest Reporters and the resuls is the same. Debug messages are still shown. Even if I explicitly set the log level to `:error` before running the tests and I check it in the tests, debug messages are still shown. Very weird...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've managed to solve this by myself.

In `config/environments/test.rb` I've added the following lines:

```
config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
config.log_level = :error
```

`ActiveRecord::Base.logger` uses the above configuration if not stated otherwise. To customize its behavior, either set `config.active_record.logger` or create a `config.after_initialize` block and set `ActiveRecord::Base.logger` in it.

This way, there is a centralized location for configuring the test logging level, where you can opt to output all messages or just some of them.

As a note, queries performed belong to `ActiveRecord::Base.logger`, and they are logged on the `:info` level. So, in order to hide them, set the log level to something higher than `:info`.

Comment: Solved my problem. The strange thing is that this became to happen overnight, any ideas what could be the causer?